# Real time stream puppeteer audio to another browser

Tags: node.js, http-live-streaming, mediastream

I'm creating a server which runs puppeteer and record the sound in a page.

I've completed recording audio to `.webm` file using `MediaRecorder` API. Now, I would like to know how to stream the audio to another browser (such as Safari).

My Node.js server is built with Fastify, but it can be any web server if it can stream the audio. So what I want do is like this:

```
------- Server(Node.js) ---------
|                               |
|  Puppeteer --> Fastify   -->  | --> Safari
---------------------------------
```

I've tried to convert `.webm` file into `.m3u8` (HLS) , but no luck (iPhone Safari couldn't play it). And It requires `ffmpeg` so I would like to avoid it if possible.

[edited]

For more context, I use Twilio Video to forward audio from a React Native app to Puppeteer. Furthermore, I use Azure speech to text service to convert audio into text in real-time.

So all system is like this:

```
React Native (iOS/Android)
  ↓
Twilio Video
  ↓
------- Server(Node.js) ---------
|                               |
|  Puppeteer --> Fastify   -->  | --> Safari
---------------------------------
  ↓
Azure speech recognition service
```

I don't want to send audio from Twilio to Safari directly, because it requires to use Twilio's Group Call plan which costs a little bit, whereas Twilio Go plan is completely free.

I know this is a complicated service, but the only thing I can't build is the live streaming of Puppeteer audio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just trying to understand everything here, you have puppeteer connecting to some website, and getting that audio into a webm file currently? Where does fastify come into play?

Comment: dir, thank you for your response. Yes, I'm running puppeteer on my server connecting to some website and getting that audio. I want to stream the audio from puppeteer to another browser (Safari). Fastify is my main server, but it can be any web server if it can pipe puppeteer's audio into audio streaming. Thanks!